# Python setter without argument?

Tags: python, properties, setter

I'm using the property and setter decorators int he following way:

```
class PCAModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.M_inv = None

    @property
    def M_inv(self):
        return self.__M_inv

    @M_inv.setter
    def set_M_inv(self):
        M = self.var * np.eye(self.W.shape[1]) + np.matmul(self.W.T, self.W)
        self.__M_inv = np.linalg.inv(M)
```

This generates an error in the `__init__` function because my setter is not taking an argument:

```
TypeError: M_inv() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I don't want to set the `M_inv` with an argument, since the calculations of `M_inv` rely solely on other properties of the class object. I could put a dummy argument in the setter:

```
@M_inv.setter
def set_M_inv(self, foo):
    M = self.var * np.eye(self.W.shape[1]) + np.matmul(self.W.T, self.W)
    self.__M_inv = np.linalg.inv(M)
```

but that feels dirty. Is there a better way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point of setters and getters, although the names are pretty self-explanatory. If your parameter is calculated independently from what you are trying to *set* (you want to ommit the argument in the setter), then a setter is just not needed at all. Since all you wanna do is calculate this parameter for each instance, just calculate and return the value in the getter, so you will be *getting* the correct, newly-calculated value each time you try to access your parameter.

```
    @property
    def M_inv(self):
        M = self.var * np.eye(self.W.shape[1]) + np.matmul(self.W.T, self.W)
        return np.linalg.inv(M)
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I want to be able to have a getter for getting the current value, and then a function for updating the value separately. This way I can get the "old" value before updating M_inv and getting the "new" value. Perhaps just having a getter and then having a simple function `update_M_inv`is the way to go? Or maybe not even a getter is needed since we don't need any pre-processing of the property?

Comment: In that case, I think your approach of having an update function is the best way to solve your problem in an object-oriented conforming way!

Comment: @Sahand Why not just drop the `@M_inv.setter` decorator to have "calculate" method with the same name as a getter method but without an argument. Not nice but function naming is up to you...